# unable to see levels after plots variables grouped

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I grouped plots in indicator like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028412/how-to-make-plots-variables-grouped-in-styles-tab) It worked and grouped my plots as I wanted. But after that, lines become [invisible.](https://i.postimg.cc/kGwwQNSZ/Untitled-11.jpg) Please help me to fix this.

Here is the original script.

```html
ADR1_high = plot(_adr1_high, title=text_ADR1_high, color=ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color_ADR1_high, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
ADR2_high = plot(_adr2_high, title=text_ADR2_high, color=ta.change(_adr2_high) ? na : color_ADR2_high, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
ADR1_low = plot(_adr1_low, title=text_ADR1_low, color=ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color_ADR1_low, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
ADR2_low = plot(_adr2_low, title=text_ADR2_low, color=ta.change(_adr2_low) ? na : color_ADR2_low, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
fill(ADR1_high, ADR2_high, title=text_upper_fill, color = ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color.new(adrUppercolorfill, 80))
fill(ADR1_low, ADR2_low, title=text_lower_fill, color = ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color.new(adrlowercolorfill, 80))
```

This is code I added and changed.

```html
ADR = 1
showADRInput = input(true, "Show ADR", group='ADR')
ADR1_high = plot(_adr1_high ? ADR : na, title=text_ADR1_high, color=ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color_ADR1_high, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
ADR2_high = plot(_adr2_high ? ADR : na, title=text_ADR2_high, color=ta.change(_adr2_high) ? na : color_ADR2_high, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
ADR1_low = plot(_adr1_low ? ADR : na, title=text_ADR1_low, color=ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color_ADR1_low, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
ADR2_low = plot(_adr2_low ? ADR : na, title=text_ADR2_low, color=ta.change(_adr2_low) ? na : color_ADR2_low, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
fill(ADR1_high, ADR2_high, title=text_upper_fill, color = ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color.new(adrUppercolorfill, 80))
fill(ADR1_low, ADR2_low, title=text_lower_fill, color = ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color.new(adrlowercolorfill, 80))
```

Comment: Please don't include your code as a link. Copy&paste it here and use the code blocks.

Comment: If I include both scripts, it will make a long question. That's why I did that. Sorry. Do I need to edit the question?

Comment: It won't be that big if you use the code blocks. Yes, please edit your question.

Comment: Also, you should always post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and not your whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part in your plot function: `_adr1_high ? ADR : na`, it will just draw `1` instead of `_adr1_high` as you defined `ADR = 1`, so technically the lines are not invisible, it's just the value is too small, you can adjust price scale to see them. This has nothing to do with grouping.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
ADR1_high = plot(showADRInput ? _adr1_high : na, title=text_ADR1_high, color=ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color_ADR1_high, style=plot.style_circles)
```

Comment: please check the new question